# Creating fingerprint file from flat file in python

Tags: python

I have another newbie python question. I have a file as shown below. I need to convert it to vector and fingerprint like form. For me the problem is how to combine the files so in final I have the matrix where rows are cmps and columns are val... and if the val is missing for the comp then equal to zero. The vals for cmp are different and overlap is not very big. Can you please suggest where to go better? Python dictionaries? Any ideas help. Thank's!

```
cmp1    0.277   val_1
cmp1    0.097   val_2
cmp1    0.795   val_3
cmp1    0.809   val_4
cmp1    0.127   val_5
cmp2    0.839   val_3
cmp2    0.909   val_4
cmp2    0.148   val_5
cmp2    0.938   val_6
cmp2    0.599   val_7
```

**results I neen to receive....**

vector version

```
name    val_1   val_2   val_3   val_4   val_5   val_6   val_7
cmp1    0.277   0.097   0.795   0.809   0.127   0   0
cmp2    0   0   0.839   0.909   0.148   0.938   0.599
```

binary version

```
name    val_1   val_2   val_3   val_4   val_5   val_6   val_7
cmp1    0   0   1   1   0   0   0
cmp2    0   0   1   1   0   1   1
```

current code

```
import csv

fi = open("data.txt", "rb")
fo = open("data_out.txt", "wb")
reader = csv.reader(fi,delimiter='\t')
writer = csv.writer(fo,delimiter='\t')

# making unique lists
targets = set()
ligands = set()

for row in reader:
    ligands.add(row[0])
    targets.add(row[2])

data = []
for row in reader:
    if row[0] in ligands and row[2] in targets:
    else:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` here:

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open('abc') as f:
    dic = defaultdict(dict)
    for line in f:
        cmp, val, col = line.split()
        dic[cmp][col] = val
print dic
# defaultdict(<type 'dict'>,
 #{'cmp1': {'val_5': '0.127', 'val_4': '0.809', 'val_1': '0.277', 'val_3': '0.795', 'val_2': '0.097'},
 # 'cmp2': {'val_5': '0.148', 'val_4': '0.909', 'val_7': '0.599', 'val_6': '0.938', 'val_3': '0.839'}})

#get a sroted list of all val_i from the dic        
vals = sorted(set(y for x in dic.itervalues() for y in x))

keys = sorted(dic)
print "name    {}".format("\t".join(vals))
for key in keys:
    print "{}    {}".format(key, "\t".join(dic[key].get(v,'0')  for v in vals)  )
```

**Output:**

```
name    val_1   val_2   val_3   val_4   val_5   val_6   val_7
cmp1    0.277   0.097   0.795   0.809   0.127   0   0
cmp2    0   0   0.839   0.909   0.148   0.938   0.599
```

For binary version you can try:

```
print "name    {}".format("\t".join(vals))
for key in keys:
    strs = "\t".join(str(int(round(float(dic[key][v])))) if v in dic[key] else '0'  for v in vals)
    print "{}    {}".format(key, strs )
```

**output:**

```
name    val_1   val_2   val_3   val_4   val_5   val_6   val_7
cmp1    0   0   1   1   0   0   0
cmp2    0   0   1   1   0   1   1
```

Comment: I am using Python2.7 - and receive current error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: replacing "{ }    { }" with "{0}    {1}" - did the trick! THANK YOU!